# distributed cache between rabbitmq consumers

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, caching, ehcache

I have a java app based on spring and hibernate 4 and rabbitmq. I have 10 different virtual linux servers, each of them running 10 java rabbitmq consumers. I need to have a cache which may be used by all of those customers. Some of them will write, then read, etc. I have spring ehcache in the project, and I use it to cache data in one application, but what should I use to make a global cache between all servers? I guess I need to install a separate server, but what is better to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of version 2.10.0, Ehcache can be clustered with Terracotta using only open source software. The setup requires indeed at least one dedicated Terracotta server, two if you want high availability.

I would recommend testing with the latest version at this time - Ehcache 2.10.1 / Terracotta 4.3.1 - see [here for downloads](http://terracotta.org/downloads/open-source/catalog).

There are of course other open source alternatives, with different setup, features, etc ...